# Fastest way to find an item in a sorted ArrayList

Tags: java

In Java, I have an ArrayList with a list of objects. Each object has a date field that is just a long data type. The ArrayList is sorted by the date field. I want to insert a new object into the ArrayList so that it appears in the correct position with regard to its date. The only solution I can see is to iterate through all the items and compare the date field of the object being inserted to the objects being iterated on and then insert it once I reach the correct position. This will be a performance issue if I have to insert a lot of records.

What are some possible ways to improve this performance? Maybe an ArrayList is not the best solution?

Comment: You can use binary search to find the insertion point.

Comment: Specifcally, [`Collections.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator)). But no, an ArrayList is most likely not the best structure for this.

Comment: You may want consider using different collection type, possibly `TreeSet` and make your items `Comparable`. Then you get everything out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that you are correct in making the statement:

> Maybe an ArrayList is not the best solution

Personally, I think that a tree structure would be better suited for this. Specifically  **Binary Search Tree**, which is sorted on the object's date time. Once you have the tree created, you can use binary search which would take *O(log n)* time.

Comment: There is a `TreeSet` in Java exactly for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using `TreeSet` and make your item `Comparable`. Then you get everything out of the box.

If this is not possible I would search for the index via `Collections.binarySearch(...)`.

**EDIT:** Make sure performance is an issue before you start optimizing

Comment: Don't think about performance until you know it's an issue?! Definitely disagree with you. That's like saying don't get a strong rope to go rock climbing if you don't think you'll need it. It's better to produce efficient code the 1st time, rather than go back and change it after it's a problem.

Comment: The real advice is "always think about performance, but don't guess---measure".

Comment: Marko got it right. I just saw so many people doing ugly stuff only for performance gain which turned to be not needed or not be performance benefit at all ...

Comment: @JanZyka True, but OP specifically mentioned that he wants to improve performance, even at the expense of using something other than ArrayList.

Comment: @EvanBechtol: true. Therefore I suggested the TreeSet at first place. My last comment about performance wasn't necessary at all. Agree

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not binary search + O(n) insertion is bad for you depends on at least these things:

- size of the list,
- access pattern (mostly insert or mostly read),
- space considerations (`ArrayList` is far more compact than the alternatives).

Given the existence of these factors and their quite complex interactions you should not switch over to a binary search tree-based solution until you find out how bad your current design is—through measurements. The switch might even make things worse for you.

Answer (score 1):

first you should sort ArrayList Using:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
...
Collections.sort(arr);
```

Then Your Answer is:

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(arr , 5);
```